# training loss remains constant even though CNN, optimizers etec are changed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a CNN with OSU RGB Thermal dataset to predict bounding boxes for pedestrians. I have collected images with only one person walking in the frame and compiled the dataset. I have written a simple CNN with image input and bounding box output. The code is as given below.

```
import os,cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
#from cairocffi import *
import pandas as pd
import csv

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
#from sklearn.metrics import mean_poisson_deviance
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import median_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D,BatchNormalization
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tfback

def _get_available_gpus():
    """Get a list of available gpu devices (formatted as strings).

    # Returns
        A list of available GPU devices.
    """
    #global _LOCAL_DEVICES
    if tfback._LOCAL_DEVICES is None:
        devices = tf.config.list_logical_devices()
        tfback._LOCAL_DEVICES = [x.name for x in devices]
    return [x for x in tfback._LOCAL_DEVICES if 'device:gpu' in x.lower()]

tfback._get_available_gpus = _get_available_gpus

PATH = os.getcwd()
# Define data path
data_path = PATH + '/frames2'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)


num_epoch=100
num_channel = 1
num_classes = 1
Y = np.zeros((1934,4))


i2=0  
with open('unified.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',', quotechar=',',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        Y[i2][:]=row
        




img_data_list=[]
#img_data=[]
#t = 1
# note I have to give two folder structure for this code to work so "frames/dzire"
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=sorted(os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset))
    #print(data_path+'/'+dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        input_img=cv2.imread(data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img ) 
        #input_img = input_img[0:201,0:201] 
        #print(input_img.shape)               
        input_img=cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
        #print(input_img.shape)  
        img_data_list.append(input_img)
        #print(t)
        #t+=1
        

#print(t)
print(input_img.shape) # 1080 X 1920

print(img_data_list[0].shape)
img_data = (np.array(img_data_list))
print(img_data.shape)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')   # problem occurs in this statement when the all input images are not of common shape(first check)
img_data /= 255
img_data= np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=1) 
print (img_data.shape)


x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=42)
# Split the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

print((X_train.shape),(y_train.shape),(X_test.shape),(y_test.shape))

# Defining the model



input_shape=img_data[0].shape   
print(input_shape)              
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal', strides = 1, input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32,kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size = 3, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(4))


opt = RMSprop(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss= "mean_squared_error",optimizer=opt,metrics=[])

model.summary()
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=num_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))


model.save("unified_cnn_v1.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

#plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
#plt.show()
```

No matter what I change in CNN parameters the output loss is always latching to "19.2.." and validation loss is always near zero.

```
Train on 1353 samples, validate on 581 samples
Epoch 1/100
2020-08-31 22:00:38.787590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-31 22:00:39.047776: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-31 22:00:40.059817: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
1353/1353 [==============================] - 30s 22ms/step - loss: 94.4755 - val_loss: 1.1403e-05
Epoch 2/100
1353/1353 [==============================] - 28s 21ms/step - loss: 19.2036 - val_loss: 2.5019e-07
Epoch 3/100
1353/1353 [==============================] - 28s 21ms/step - loss: 19.3207 - val_loss: 2.4980e-07
Epoch 4/100
```

I have changed no of layers, tried different optimizers with different lr's but the loss is always the same. I can not get a reasonable explanation for this behaviour. I have checked various blogs etc and mostly it was mentioned that dataset is not proper etc. I have checked the dataset and assigned bbox co-ordinates. They are proper. The coord correctly enclose the target in all the images.
I want to understand under what kind of circumstances does the data always give same output. in my case loss of "19.2.." for different CNNs, optimizers etc. Its not constant output for different CNNS, nut same constant '19.2..." for any change. Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say it is not changing ? 94.4755 -> 19.2036 -> 19.3207 ?

Comment: its always coming to 19.2.. in second epoch and is varying in 3rd or 4th decimal till next 98 epochs.

Comment: I recommend you to first check if you really get a very good result on your validation dataset and take actions then.

Comment: @lincr I don’t understand..I have one dataset with 1900 images..I am splitting the dataset with 0.7: 0.3 For training and validating. Once the network is trained, I can test for other datasets. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ideally, you should split your data into 3 parts. Train set, Validation set, and test set. The validation set is used for parameter tuning while the test set is used to test your tuned model.

Comment: I am not able to train the model. I observe a very peculiar Behaviour, I Changed CNN model drastically, still In all the configurations the loss is stuck at the same value “19.2xyz”( xyz are decimals). How can this happen? Can anyone  explain this behaviour. Can the dataset be problematic? Is it possible?

Comment: I found the problem. Silly one , I am not incrementing i2 for csv file. That’s why loss is always constant. Will update if the problem I solved.

Comment: Problem solved. Closing the post.